# Windows sound jumps to full volume when toggling a light switch in the house

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

I encounter a weird issue when toggling a light switch in the house. My laptop is playing music, connected to an external mixer via USB, PC monitor via HDMI, and plugged into the wall outlet. Every time the light switch is toggled, the Windows sound jumps to full volume. How could this even happen?

Comment: You might want to check your electrical ground.  Also, if you are not currently using a good surge suppressor for your laptop, mixer, and PC monitor, use one.

Comment: Yes, actually the grounding is not too great in my house, and I'm sure this must have something to do with it, but I'm trying to understand what actually happens with the hardware/software, as it seems so random

Comment: My guess is that voltage (surge/drop) is flowing back into your laptop via the USB or HDMI cable, which your OS is misinterpreting as a 'change volume' command.  Dry winter months can also cause unpredictable results when static discharge is introduced.  Anti-static mats can help a bit too.